# Exception Handling and Opening a File?

Tags: c++, exception, inputstream, file-handling

Is it possible to use exceptions with file opening as an alternative to using `.is_open()`?

For example:

```
ifstream input;

try{
  input.open("somefile.txt");
}catch(someException){
  //Catch exception here
}
```

If so, what type is `someException`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions

Answer (score 54, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions

Also read this answer [11085151](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085151/c-ifstream-failbit-and-badbit) which references this [article](https://gehrcke.de/2011/06/reading-files-in-c-using-ifstream-dealing-correctly-with-badbit-failbit-eofbit-and-perror/)

```
// ios::exceptions
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void do_something_with(char ch) {} // Process the character 

int main () {
  ifstream file;
  file.exceptions ( ifstream::badbit ); // No need to check failbit
  try {
    file.open ("test.txt");
    char ch;
    while (file.get(ch)) do_something_with(ch);
    // for line-oriented input use file.getline(s)
  }
  catch (const ifstream::failure& e) {
    cout << "Exception opening/reading file";
  }

  file.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Sample code running on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dbLvyj3nPfOpD6Te)

EDIT: catch exceptions by const reference [2145147](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145147/why-catch-an-exception-as-reference-to-const)

EDIT: removed failbit from the exception set. Added URLs to better answers.

Comment: Do we need to use _ifstream_ _file_ as type? Could we use _ofstream_?

Comment: Assuming you are writing to a file, then yes you can manage exceptions the same way with ofstream. Use ofstream::failbit, ofstream::badbit and ofstream::failure.

Comment: @KarlM: Ehm in this case it isn't wrong. Although it _is_ redundant.

Comment: BTW catch exceptions by reference

Comment: I shall point out your code is not working as you may think. The exception will be thrown when you encounter the EOF because you set `ifstream::failbit` as exception mask, at least on Mac OS 10.10 Yesomite. If a file is read when EOF is encountered, `ios_base::failbit` will be set together with `ios_base::eofbit`.

Comment: If you remove `ios_base::failbit` you don't get an exception when the file does not exist. Just replace `test.txt` with `test2.txt` and see for yourself. It won't throw anything.
If you ask me, just don't use `ios_base::exceptions()`. It's completely botched up...

Answer (score 3):

From [the cplusplus.com article on `std::ios::exceptions`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/exceptions/)

> On failure, the failbit flag is set (which can be checked with member fail), and depending on the value set with exceptions an exception may be thrown.