# C++ ifstream failbit and badbit

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

In case of `ifstream` in C++, under what conditions are `failbit` and `badbit` flags set ?

Comment: http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/

Comment: @Jake Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com):

> **failbit** is generally set by an input operation when the error was related to the internal logic of the operation itself, so other operations on the stream may be possible. While **badbit** is generally set when the error involves the loss of integrity of the stream, which is likely to persist even if a different operation is performed on the stream. badbit can be checked independently by calling member function bad.

In *simple words*, if you get a **number** when expect to retrieve a **letter**, it's `failbit`. If a **serious** error happens, which disrupts the ability to read from the stream at all - it's a `badbit`.

Except mentioned flags there is a third quite similar — `eofbit`. You can check the state using several functions: [`ios::fail`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/), [`ios::good`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/) and [`ios::bad`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/bad/)

And you can get familiar with [**iostream library**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277347%28v=vs.60%29) at MSDN resource too.

**Finally**, if you search for the **correct** solution of how to handling all error bits and exceptions while reading from the file (or accessing some file or directory), I highly recommend you read a very comprehensive and well-written article "[Reading files in C++ using ifstream: dealing correctly with badbit, failbit, eofbit, and perror()](http://gehrcke.de/2011/06/reading-files-in-c-using-ifstream-dealing-correctly-with-badbit-failbit-eofbit-and-perror/)", at the end of which you will find a few **[Ideal solutions](http://gehrcke.de/2011/06/reading-files-in-c-using-ifstream-dealing-correctly-with-badbit-failbit-eofbit-and-perror/#ideal)**. The article is worth to read indeed.