# Does ifstream::close reset failbit and/or badbit?

Tags: c++, error-handling, fstream

Does calling [`ifstream::close`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/close/) reset the stream's `failbit` and/or `badbit`, similar to calling [`clear`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/)? This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085151/c-ifstream-failbit-and-badbit)- I need to know whether the flags are *reset*, not just when they're *set*.

For example, I'm using something like the following `if-else` in my current project:

```
ifstream myInputStream("foo.txt");

//Let's pretend this compiles all the time, even though it
//might not because the operator is ambiguous.
myInputStream << "Outputting to an input stream causes problems."

if (myInputStream.fail())
{
   cout << "Aw, nuts. It failed." << endl;
   myInputStream.close();
   return false;
}
else
{
   cout << "No nuts here. Only chocolate chips." << endl;
   myInputStream.close();
   return true;
}
```

Do I have to have the call to `myInputStream.close` after the call to `myInputStream.fail`, in each branch, to get an accurate check? Or will this work:

```
ifstream myInputStream("foo.txt");

myInputStream << "Outputting to an input stream causes problems.";    

myInputStream.close();

if (myInputStream.fail())
{
   cout << "Aw, nuts. It failed." << endl;
   return false;
}
else
{
   cout << "No nuts here. Only chocolate chips." << endl;
   return true;
}
```

I know that [`ifstream::close`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/close/) can itself **set** `failbit` or `badbit` if closing fails, which is one reason I want to call it before checking for failure- I need to return false regardless of what caused it. It also looks less cluttered if the closure is only done once.

### **tl;dr;**

Does [`ifstream::close`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/close/) **reset** `failbit` or `badbit` if something else has already set it, making my second code sample return true?

Comment: _"Do I have to have the call to myInputStream.close after the call to myInputStream.fail, in each branch, to get an accurate check?"_ Why do you need to call `close()` at all? Closing an `fstream` _can_ fail, but most programs don't need to check for it failing, so can just let the destructor close the file. Why do you care if closing an _input_ stream fails? You don't have to worry about any pending writes being flushed to the file if it's an input stream.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/close

Comment: I need to call `close()` because the file might need to be opened again fro reading or for writing before the object is guaranteed to be destructed, depending on user input. I could refactor to avoid this, but using `close()` after the file's read is also a requirement for my class. I guess that's mostly why I need to use it :P

Comment: So you're not really doing `return true` / `return false` as in the example above? In that code calling `close()` just before the object is destroyed anyway is completely pointless. I would try to structure the code so you construct an ifstream when you need to open a file and destroy it when you're done with it, rather than keeping a long-lived object that you open/close repeatedly.

Comment: The code in my example is similar to what I'm actually doing, but the code is inside a function that takes a reference to an already-open ifstream, does some checking, and then sometimes closes it. I feel like this is a bad control flow, because the caller can't expect whether the stream it passes will still be open, but it's a part of the assignment. I think our professor might be having us do things in a simple way that works, even if it isn't the best, so we can improve on our own code later in the semester with more complicated concepts. That seems to be his M.O.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`close()` should not clear any of the state flags, although it might set `failbit` depending on the return value of the underlying buffer.

[fstream.members] (also [ifstream.members] and [ofstream.members])

> `void close();`
>
> Effects: Calls `rdbuf()->close()` and, if that function returns returns a null pointer, calls `setstate(failbit)` (27.5.5.4) (which may throw `ios_base::failure`).

The flags *are* cleared by `open()` however, assuming the filebuf opens correctly

> `void open(const char* s, ios_base::openmode mode =
>   ios_base::in|ios_base::out);`
>
> Effects: Calls `rdbuf()->open(s,mode)`.
>   If that function does not return a null pointer calls `clear()`,
>   otherwise calls `setstate(failbit)`, (which may throw `ios_base::failure`)
>   (27.5.5.4).

Comment: That clears things up. Thank you. Good to know that `open` clears the flags.

Comment: @MichaelHoffmann I can't say I've ever needed either of these functions, but then again most of my file error checking boils down to "did reading or writing something fail? Throw error."

Comment: Ah. Destructors. *facepalm*. How did I forget about destructors? I've been in Python land too long :P

Answer (score 1):

Using the example code in the question (modified so it compiles with g++), it looks like [`ifstream::close`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/close/) **does not** reset `failbit`. I don't know about `badbit`, however ([`ios::fail`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/) returns true if either is set).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   ofstream writer("foo.txt");

   writer << "These are not integers.";

   writer.close();

   ifstream myInputStream("foo.txt");

   int i;
   myInputStream >> i;//This should set the failbit.

   myInputStream.close();//Will this reset it?

   if (myInputStream.fail())
   {
      cout << "Aw, nuts. It failed." << endl;
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "No nuts here. Only chocolate chips." << endl;
      return true;
   }
}
```

**Output:** Aw, nuts. It failed.

`myInputStream.fail()` is returning false.

Comment: Reading from a deleted file doesn't cause a problem, the file is not deleted while there is an open file handle to it. So you are not observing the state being reset, it was just always clear.