# ios::exceptions(...) changes when badbit is set

Tags: c++, exception, iostream, ifstream

When executing the following code, I get the following output: EOF FAIL. So reading a line from an empty file sets eofbit and failbit, **but not badbit**.

If I enable exceptions by uncommenting line 11 the output changes: EOF BAD FAIL. Now reading a line from an empty file sets eofbit, badbit, **but not failbit** (otherwise an exception had occured).

Can someone explain why enabling exceptions changes the way, failbit and badbit are set. Is this documented somewhere?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    ifstream f("some_empty_file");
    string line;

    // f.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit); // (line 11)

    getline(f, line);
    if(f.eof()) cout << "EOF ";
    if(f.bad()) cout << "BAD ";
    if(f.fail()) cout << "FAIL ";

    cout << endl;
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I read the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085193/3821618 on the difference of badbit and failbit. But that does not answer the question, why with exceptions enabled, reading from an empty file becomes a "**serious** error", while it is not, if I do not call f.exceptions(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 distinct stream states (taken from [std::ios_base::iostate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate)):

> ```
>  typedef /*implementation defined*/ iostate;
>  static constexpr iostate goodbit = 0;
>  static constexpr iostate badbit = /*implementation defined*/
>  static constexpr iostate failbit = /*implementation defined*/
>  static constexpr iostate eofbit = /*implementation defined*/
> ```

So setting of the `eofbit` doesn't necessarily trigger your exception mask.

Comment: Neither with nor without the call to `f.exception(..)` an exception is triggered. It it only the result of `f.bad()` that changes. Why so?

Comment: @JAyP [I can't really see any behavior changing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd1d35f7aa25fcb3)?

Comment: Interesting: no changing behavior with gcc5.4 on gnu/linux, but **it does change** with clang-800.0.42.1 on macos. I did not thought of this to be platform depended. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JAyP There are the `/*implementation defined*/` comments.