# Why does std::ifstream not throw an exception even when exceptions are specifically enabled?

Tags: c++, gcc, ifstream

So, by default `std::ifstream` doesn't throw an exception when you open an invalid file path. It rather silently fails and if you don't use the `fail()` method or similar to check, it will easily go unnoticed which is quite bad.

Since I want to get exceptions on any kind of failures so I can be informed automatically, I tried using the `exceptions()` method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279023/3764804):

```
std::ifstream input_stream;
input_stream.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit);
input_stream.open(file_path);
```

To my surprise this **still** doesn't throw an exception if the file path does not exist. I tried using `std::ios::badbit` instead but same result.

I tested on `Ubuntu` with `GCC`.

Why does this not work as expected?

Comment: Take another look at [documentation for `open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open).

Comment: Re: "which is quite bad" -- it doesn't silently fail. You can check that it succeeded. And any input operations will also fail. You can't just blindly try a bunch of input without ever checking whether it succeeded. Lots of programmers successfully write complex programs without requiring exceptions on I/O failures.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Sure but checking return values is quite an outdated and cumbersome way of programming when we have exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On failure, `open()` sets `failbit`, not `badbit`.  You are not asking the `ifstream` to throwing an exception on `failbit`.