# Catch exception by const reference and cast away const

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer

Is this valid as an exception handler, where `T` is some class with a non-`const` member function `func`?

In other words: is the `catch` guaranteed to bind directly to the (modifiable) exception object,  or is there latitude for the compiler to do some trickery when you catch by const reference?

```
catch(const T &t)
{
    const_cast<T &>(t).func();
}
```

Comment: Whyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy??

Comment: because Matt is apparently a language lawyer

Comment: @dufresnb: That is absolutely no reason to write code like this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so I can respond definitively to someone else who wrote this code

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Haha okay then. Still. The answer is "you're safe but stupid" so just answer with confidence and let that be that.

Comment: Why do you have a `const` after the `catch` to begin with?

Comment: @fredoverflow some people recommend to catch exceptions by const reference (although I'm yet to see a good explanation for this)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Not when you want to mutate them, no.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In the case in question, the `func()` is not being used to mutate the exception, only to read some data from it, but `func()` itself is not declared as `const`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That design flaw notwithstanding, from an outside perspective I _must_ treat it as though it's a mutation. That's literally what lack of `const` means on a member function. If it doesn't actually modify any data then that's a design flaw but I can't and won't reason about that externally. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In this case, the object type being thrown is coming from a library that uses very little `const`-correctness in C++, and in this case class member functions are never declared as `const`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: (a) Yeah, that's all well and good, I'm just saying that does not come into the picture when discussing general guidelines for exception handling. It's an exception [sic] to the rule, caused by poor design. (b) How do you know?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: (b) because I know the situation MattMcNabb is asking about, it is based on comments we exchanged in [another discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524633/). This question is keeping the details vague to focus on the core C++ issue without getting into vendor specifics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: (b) Okay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [except.throw]:

> Evaluating a throw-expression with an operand throws an exception (15.1); the type of the exception object
>   is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualifiers from the static type of the operand and adjusting the
>   type from “array of T” or “function returning T” to “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T”,
>   respectively.

and, emphasis mine:

> Throwing an exception copy-initializes (8.5, 12.8) a temporary object, called the exception object. The
>   temporary is an **lvalue** and is used to initialize the variable declared in the matching handler (15.3).

So if we throw an operand of type *cv* T, we're copy-initializing a temporary object of type T.

Then according to [except.handle], a handler for const T& (for non-pointer-type T) is matched for an exception object of type E if:

> - [...] E and T are the same type (ignoring the top-level *cv-qualifiers*),
> - [...] T is an unambiguous public base class of E

This handler is initialized by:

> The variable declared by the exception-declaration, of type *cv* T or *cv* T&, is initialized from the exception
>   object, of type E, as follows:
>   — if T is a base class of E, the variable is copy-initialized (8.5) from the corresponding base class subobject
>   of the exception object;
>   — otherwise, the variable is copy-initialized (8.5) from the exception object.

So if we catch by const T&, we're copy-initializing the reference from the exception object - which we know from the previous section will be either of type T or is derived publicly from T. From [dcl.init.ref]:

> A reference to type “*cv1* T1” is initialized by an expression of type “*cv2* T2” as follows:
>   — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>     — is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “*cv1* T1” is reference-compatible with “*cv2* T2”, or [...]
>
> then the reference is bound to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case

The key is that the temporary exception object is still an *lvalue*. Thus, if our handler was matched for const T&, we know that the reference is bound directly to an object of type T or D (where D derives from T) - either way, it's a type that is reference-compatible with `const T`. As such, there is no undefined behavior. If the temporary object were an rvalue or the handler could match a wider range of types, then  a temporary would be created of type `const T` - and your `const_cast` would definitely be undefined behavior.

While your code exhibits no undefined behavior on a conforming compiler, there's really no reason not to just do:

```
catch(T &t)
{
    t.func();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

(I'm using C++11; I need to update ;))

15.1/3 (emphasis mine):

> A *throw-expression* initializes a temporary object, called the exception object, **the type of which is determined by removing any top-level cv-qualiﬁers** from the static type of the operand of throw

This means that the exception object is never "born const" and as such should not trigger undefined behavior to modify.

Comment: That looks pretty conclusive; nice.

Comment: FWIW the wording is the same in C++14

Comment: Technically this doesn't prove that the ref binds to this above defined object and there's no "trickery" but, as in my own answer, you can't disprove a negative. And why _would_ it work that way anyway? The question's kind of unclear on precisely what trickery we are being required to disprove, so...

Comment: My question is whether the `catch` must bind directly to that object. Barry's (deleted) answer starts to go into this . Initializing a const reference by copy-initialization sometimes creates a temporary.

Comment: @Barry: N4527 is not a standard. Interesting that this might change in C++17 though? Is there similar wording?

Comment: @Barry: The sentence after the one I quoted says "The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable named in the matching handler"

Answer (score 3):

I see no evidence of any "trickery" in the standard. Can't prove a negative, but I believe you're "safe". The `const`ness appears to be equivalent in form to this:

```
T obj;
const T& t = obj;
const_cast<T &>(t).func();
```

That is, the `const`ness first comes into being on the reference that exists within the `catch` block and that's that.

But this all really begs the question: if you can't be sure by looking at it, why do it at all?

Just catch a `T&`, surely.

Answer (score 0):

As it says [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch):

> If the parameter of the catch-clause is a reference type, any changes made to it are reflected in the exception object, and can be observed by another handler if the exception is rethrown with throw;

So this suggests that it's safe to modify the exception object, and the changes will be observable.

However, one should consider just catching by an ordinary reference. Or, make the function `const` if it can work only on members that are marked as `mutable`.

Any of this doesn't sound readable and can make co-developers hostile.

Comment: Not really answering the question.

Comment: That means if you take by reference and rethrow, the handler of the rethrow can see your changes. It doesn't mean modifiying anything taken by `const&` is OK.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question is "is the catch guaranteed to bind directly to the (modifiable) exception object". The quote suggests that it is.

Comment: @BillyONeal `const T&` is a reference type, so the quote seems relevant, even if not directly.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Oh, I suppose so. Would be clearer if you added that conclusion to the answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, thanks. Anyway, the answer by Billy ONeal seems to be the spot-on.