# where can we use "try catch" and exception?

Tags: visual-c++

How to throw a C++ exception
c++ exception-handling
I have a very poor understanding of exception handling(i.e., how to customize throw, try, catch statements for my own purposes).

For example, I have defined a function as follows: int compare(int a, int b){...}

I'd like the function to throw an exception with some message when either a or b is negative.

How should I approach this in the definition of the function?

Comment: You might want to read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279678.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Not at all.

The *definition* of the function stays

```
int compare(int a, int b);
```

whether or not you throw an exception (forget about [`throw(exception)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec), it's considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055407/7571171) and is deprecated).

---

If you want to throw an exception if either a or b is negative, you put this code in your methods *implementation*:

```
int compare(int a, int b)
{
    if(a < 0 || b < 0)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("a and be must be positive");
    }

    // the comparing code here
}
```

and that's all it takes for the method to throw. Note that you need to `#include <stdexcept>`.

---

For the calling code (e.g. `main`) you would do it this way:

```
int result;

try
{
    result = compare(42, -10);
}
catch(const std::logic_error& ex)
{
    // Handle the exception here. You can access the exception and it's members by using the 'ex' object.
}
```

Note how we [catch the exception as a const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145555/7571171) in the `catch` clause so that you can access the exceptions members such as `ex.what()` which gives you the exception message, in this case

> "a and be must be positive"

---

Note.
You can of course throw other exception types (even your own, custom exceptions), but for this example I found `std::logic_error` the most appropriate, since it reports [a faulty logic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error).