# c++ overriding exception::what()

Tags: c++, exception

I have a custom exception which is

```
class RenterLimitException : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what();
};
```

What is the proper way to override what()? For now, I created this custom in a header file and want to override what() in my cpp file.
My function is defined as following:

```
const char* RenterLimitException::what(){
    return "No available copies.";
}
```

However, when I use my try/catch block, it doesn't print the message that I gave to my function what(), instead, it prints `std::exception`
My try/catch block is this:

```
try{
   if (something){
            throw RenterLimitException();}
}
catch(std::exception& myCustomException){
        std::cout << myCustomException.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

Is it because my try/catch block or it is my `what()` function?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `what` method has the [wrong signature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what).

Comment: @G.M. So it should be ```virtual const char*  RenterLimitException::what() const throw(){
    return "No available copies.";
}```?

Comment: In general, you should the `override` keyword, it would have warned you that your implementation does not override the `what()` method in the base class.

Comment: In modern C++, use `noexcept` specifier instead of the deprecated `throw()` exception specification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is *not* the correct signature for the `what` method, you should be using `const char * what() const noexcept override` as per the following complete program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class RenterLimitException : public std::exception {
public:
    const char * what() const noexcept override {
        return "No available copies.";
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw RenterLimitException();
    } catch (const std::exception& myCustomException) {
        std::cout << myCustomException.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Notice the specific signature used for the override and the catching of a `const` exception in `main` (not absolutely necessary but a good idea nonetheless). In particular, note the `override` specifier, which will cause compilers to actually *check* that the function you're specifying is a virtual one provided by a base class.

Said program prints, as expected:

```
No available copies.
```

Comment: you should probably what to catch by const reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145147/why-catch-an-exception-as-reference-to-const

Comment: Use `override` instead of `virtual`.

Comment: Done and done. Both good points, bods, appreciate the input.

Comment: I also want to ask, if I have 10 custom exceptions like this, one catch could catch all thrown?

Comment: @Alex if they all publicly derive from `std::exception`, yes, this will catch them all. Read about dynamic polymorphism for more.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili Thank y'all, this is really helpful.

Comment: It is important to explicitly stress in your answer that the most important is "override" in it. I mean - adding `override` causes that compilers check the correctness of all other parts

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
class RenterLimitException : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept;
};
```

`const` is part of a function signature. To avoid this kind of error in the future you could also get into the habit of using `override`

```
class RenterLimitException : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept override;
};
```

`override` will give you an error if you get the signature of a virtual function wrong.